# Convert vector of ints to vector of enums in Rust

Tags: rust

```
pub enum MyEnum{
    Int(i32),
    Float(f32)
}
fn convert(my_vec:Vec<i32>) -> Vec<MyEnum>
{
    //??
}
```

I need to convert a vector of ints to a vector of enum type Int.

Comment: Note that you likely don't want to take `&Vec<i32>` - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40006219/why-is-it-discouraged-to-accept-a-reference-to-a-string-string-vec-vec-o.

Comment: Note that the return type of `convert` is `Vec<MyEnum>` not `Vec<Int>`. `Int` isn't a type, it's a variant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple [`map()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.map) + [`collect()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.collect) will do:

```rust
my_vec.iter().map(|v| MyEnum::Int(*v)).collect::<Vec<_>>()
// Or
my_vec.iter().copied().map(MyEnum::Int).collect::<Vec<_>>()
```